# Cyclic dependency in ErrorHandler

Tags: angular

I created a basic error handler that is supposed to catch errors and display them through a toaster.

```
// global.errorHandler.ts
import { ErrorHandler, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { ToastrService } from 'ngx-toastr';

@Injectable()
export class GlobalErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler {
  constructor( private toastr: ToastrService ) {}

  handleError( error ) {
    this.toastr.error( error.message );
    throw error;
  }
}
```

Then I import it into app module:

```
// app.module.ts
import { ErrorHandler, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { GlobalErrorHandler } from './global.errorHandler';
import { ToastrModule } from 'ngx-toastr';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  imports: [ ToastrModule.forRoot() ],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: ErrorHandler,
      useClass: GlobalErrorHandler
    }
  ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})

export class AppModule {}
```

And finally throw an error in `AppComponent` like `throw new Error( 'YOU DIDN\'T SAY THE MAGIC WORD' );`

On page load this logs an error in the console: `Cannot instantiate cyclic dependency!`

I tried to use the `Injector` <s>hack</s> workaround like so:

```
// global.errorHandler.ts
private toastr: ToastrService;
constructor( injector: Injector ) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    this.toastr = injector.get( ToastrService );
  });
}
```

This allows the error handler to load, but never actually executes the toast. I'm guessing it has something to do with the order in which the dependencies are loaded in Angular but I'm not sure how to resolve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove throw error from handleError method in global.errorHandler.ts

```
// global.errorHandler.ts
import { ErrorHandler, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { ToastrService } from 'ngx-toastr';

@Injectable()
export class GlobalErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler {
  constructor( private toastr: ToastrService ) {}

  handleError( error ) {
    this.toastr.error( error.message );
    // throw error;  // Remove this line
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Another possible solution will be getting ToastrService from injector rather than constructor injection, as mentioned below :

```
import { ErrorHandler, Inject, Injector, Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { ToastrService } from "ngx-toastr";

@Injectable()
export class AppErrorHandler extends ErrorHandler {

  constructor(@Inject(Injector) private injector: Injector) { 
    super(true);
  }

  // Need to get ToastrService from injector rather than constructor injection to avoid cyclic dependency error
  private get toastrService(): ToastrService {
    return this.injector.get(ToastrService);
  }

  public handleError(error: any): void {
    this.toastrService.error(
      "An unexpected error has occurred.",
      "Error",
      {
        closeButton: true,
        timeOut: 5000,
        onActivateTick: true
      }
    );

    super.handleError(error);
  }
}
```

Reference taken from : https://github.com/scttcper/ngx-toastr/issues/179#issuecomment-325724269